Spring JPA Unit test JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException after spring upgrade
I am upgrading spring from 5.0.8.RELEASE to  5.3.26 and spring boot from 2.0.2.RELEASE to 2.7.9
Updated queryDSL from 4.4.0 to 5.0.0.
Here is my JPA test config:
spring:
  profiles: "test"
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions: true
        hbm2ddl:
          import_files_sql_extractor=org: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
        connection:
          charSet: UTF-8
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
    database-platform=org:
      hibernate:
        dialect:
          H2Dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    #generate-ddl: true
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
  h2:
    console:
      path: /console
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    data: classpath:data.sql

When I run the junit tests I get the following error.**
**
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ""asset_entlmt_type"" (""asset_entlmt_type_id"" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, ""asset_entlmt_type_desc"" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR[*]), ""crtd_by"" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), ""dt_crtd"" TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (""asset_entlmt_type_id""))"; expected "CHARACTERS, OCTETS, )"; SQL statement:
create table "asset_entlmt_type" ("asset_entlmt_type_id" number(10,0) not null, "asset_entlmt_type_desc" varchar2(255 char), "crtd_by" varchar2(255 char), "dt_crtd" timestamp, primary key ("asset_entlmt_type_id")) [42001-202]**
here is the Entity its complaining about:
@Id
@Column(name = "asset_entlmt_type_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Integer assetEntitlementTypeId;

@Column(name = "asset_entlmt_type_desc")
private String assetEntitlementTypeDesc;

/** Metadata fields */

@Column(name = "crtd_by")
private String createdBy;

I tried adding all types of config properties to ignore keywords and different versions of h2 db and still the same issue. Pretty much ran out of options to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!!

The error is in the syntax of SQL. Where in the code the error is detected?

When the junit is run the test suite tries to create the tables based on the entities.
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1286) ~[h2-2.0.202.jar:2.0.202]

varchar2(255 char) is invalid syntax, should be varchar2(255)
After fixing this, it works, try
create table "asset_entlmt_type" ("asset_entlmt_type_id" number(10,0) not null, "asset_entlmt_type_desc" varchar2(255), "crtd_by" varchar2(255), "dt_crtd" timestamp, primary key ("asset_entlmt_type_id")) 


I am not sure how to fix it when its being auto generated by the jpa. Any ideas?

Try to change dialect, saying to MySQL, may be it helps

I was able to get past it by adding the property DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false; However running into
nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "TO_DATE"

What is in the log now?
